# How can I get a protected method via reflection matching name and parameters type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

Before dotnet core we were able to do

```cs
var member = type.GetMethod(name, bindingFlags, null, argtypes, null);
```

To get access to a method matching its name and parameters type, in dotnet core they removed this overload, now I can only get by `name && binding flags` OR `name && parameters type` ([see](http://dotnet.github.io/api/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.html#System_Reflection_TypeExtensions_GetMethod_System_Type_System_String_)), but not like before.

There is a new method [GetRuntimeMethods](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d0dc5fc099946adc1035b34a8b1f6042eddb0c75/src/System.Reflection.Extensions/src/System/Reflection/RuntimeReflectionExtensions.cs#L33) which returns `IEnumerable<MethodInfo>` and includes non public methods but I can't filter by parameters type.

There is another method [GetRuntimeMethod](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d0dc5fc099946adc1035b34a8b1f6042eddb0c75/src/System.Reflection.Extensions/src/System/Reflection/RuntimeReflectionExtensions.cs#L66) which I can filter by parameters type but it doesn't include non public methods.

I already tried something like this, but fails

```cs
var member = type.GetRuntimeMethods().Where(m =>
m.Name == name && (m.GetParameters().Select(p => p.GetType()).ToArray() == argtypes)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a way to get a method by its name and parameters type?

Comment: I don't think you can compare arrays like that: `m.GetParameters().Select(p => p.GetType()).ToArray() == argtypes)` - it won't compare array items but array references so it's always false. You can use `Zip` or `SequenceEqual` to compare arrays contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that overload is indeed missing. What you can use is to use `GetMethods()` and filter the output the way you want. Your attempt is close, except you can't compare arrays using `==`:

```
var method = type.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m =>
    m.Name == name && m.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(argTypes));
```

Comment: My bad! Works like a charm, I just had to change p.GetType() to p.ParameterType. Tks